# Text in squared box for preface

Tags: abstract, text

i want to make a preface, is between cover's page and index's page

but don't know how make a text like a square (how show below) without bleeding in the end and start

thanks

[image: text for preface]
here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,final,openany]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\hyphenation{trian-gu-lar}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\let\wasysymLightning\lightning
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%para estilo negrita teorema
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
   \xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} 
\makeatother
%para estilo negrita teorema
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem]{Proposición}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lema}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definición}
\newtheorem{ejem}[theorem]{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Notación}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observación}
\newtheorem*{nota}{Notación}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\author{Ja}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

%here need preface

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Pre}\label{pre}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without bleeding in the end and start"? Do you refer to the text being justified rather than left aligned (ragged right)?

Comment: I mean that it is aligned as a square, just like in the photo, it is a preface to a monograph. and dont know how do it

Comment: Text that is left and right aligned at the same time is called justified. With most standard latex classes this is the default behaviour. As this does not seem to be the case in your document, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: what example do you need, is like i show in the picture

Comment: I get what your desired output looks like. The information that is needed is the documentclass etc that you use. So please prepare a small example document and add the code to your question.

Comment: Please save us having to type everything.

Comment: there i write my code

Comment: Should your preface have wider margins than the rest of the book, like the standard `abstract` environment? And  shall it fit alone, on a single page?

Comment: in a single page, but could be have more small margin